# libcurl.dll problem with curl and c# .NET

Tags: c#, dll, curl, libcurl

I Need to develpe application for getting http website page

I found this tutorial for using curl in .Net

http://thedotnetframework.blogspot.com/2008/06/lets-talk-about-http-protocol-and-http.html

I downloaded the curl dll files and add reference (LibCurlNet.dll) to my project

and added the class in my project

but when I run my project, I have error message at line

```
Curl.GlobalInit((int)CURLinitFlag.CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
```

the error message says

```
Unable to load DLL 'libcurl.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

it seems that ibcurl.dll has a problem

note : I can not add (ibcurl.dll) as reference in my project

please help ;

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the built-in [`WebClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).
You don't need any third-party libraries.

Comment: it seems to be slow .. I need to use curl as I used it in php and it's fast and more flexible

Comment: @user: That won't be any faster.  You probably have a slow connection.  (Or you're misusing it; try using a StreamReader)

Comment: Of course there are some things that cURL can do that the .NET framework library does not such as SSH. But it sounds like it is not needed here.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is that you need that file (and LibCurlShim.dll) present in your build directory (e.g. bin\debug) or wherever your exe is running from. There is no problem with the file - you just cannot add it as a reference in the usual way in Visual Studio.

You could right-click on Project Explorer and add Existing Files and select libcurl.dll and LibCurlShim.dll. Then in Solution Explorer, on the Properties of those two files make sure you set the `Copy To Output Directory` to something like `Copy Always or Only If Newer`

[image]

Comment: Even though you got no points for it, your answer was the correct one.  I was able to use it solve my issue with the same problem OP was complaining about.  Thanks very much.